# Reducing the timeout for socket connection

Tags: sockets, server, timeout, tcl

I am here again asking for help.
Platform: Openwrt shell running on a router (but it can be any shell)
Tcl version: 8.6.11 with some few inserted packages manually from tcllib

Background: I have a minimal "bot" made of tcl that connects to an personal irc server. All working fine with some functions. Recently we had some dns issues (and we still have at this moment of writing) and no one can no longer connect to the irc server until my friends fix the dns issue. Upon the current network problem, I decided to add a retry mechanism to the bot that tries server1 and if it fails, try server2.
The servers list is just a simple tcl file with set servers {servername1 port servername2 port} (where port is 6667, until I figure out ssl).
Before I add the retry functionality, the bot simply quit after 90..190 seconds to the shell.
After I add the retry feature, bot bot switches from server to server take LONG timings like 90..190 or so. If I add manually a 3rd server with a valid connection, it connects happily after we wait for the first 2 servers to finish timeout.

Here's a result of the retry mechanism:

```
root@OpenWrt:~/tp-link# tclsh tplinkbot.tcl
Launching TP-Link ... (Pid:  4335)
[04/Apr 18:55:52] --- Attempting to connect to pie.someserver.org:6667 ...
[04/Apr 18:58:05] !!! Error connecting to pie.someserver.org: couldn't open socket: connection timed out
[04/Abr 18:58:05] --- Attempting to connect to icecream.someserver.org:6667 ...
[04/Apr 19:00:18] !!! Error connecting to icecream.someserver.org: couldn't open socket: connection timed out
[04/Abr 19:00:18] --- Attempting to connect to pie.someserver.org:6667 ...
[04/Apr 19:02:31] !!! Error connecting to pie.someserver.org: couldn't open socket: connection timed out
```

And here's the code:

```
set botconnect "s"
while 1 {
    if {$botconnect!="s"} {
        set in [gets $fd]
    }
    if {$in=="" || $botconnect=="s"} {
        source servers.tcl
        set sindex 0
        while 1 {
            catch {close $fd}
            set dstaddr [lindex $servers $sindex]
            set dstport [lindex $servers $sindex+1]
            puts stdout "[logtime] --- Attempting to connect to $dstaddr:$dstport ..."
            if {[catch {set fd [socket $dstaddr $dstport]; fconfigure $fd -async -blocking 0 -retry 0 -connect-timeout 5} errortext]} {
                puts stdout "[logtime] !!! Error connecting to $dstaddr: $errortext"
            } else {
                puts stdout "Connection successful!!!"
                break
            }
            incr sindex 2
            if {$sindex>=[llength $servers]} {set sindex 0}
            #puts stdout ">[file channels]<"
        }
        puts $fd "NICK $botnick"
        flush $fd
        puts $fd "USER $botident \"\" \"\" :$gecos"
        flush $fd
        set botconnect "n"
    }
  (...the list of scripts to load begins and executes commands for the interacting with the server and users...)
}
```

The fconfigure thing was added few moments ago while I was attempting things and it's not part of the original code.
The idea is to set a server timeout for 10 or 15 seconds and kill the connection attempt since there was no life.
Anyone can help please?

Comment: There are two slow parts to establishing a connection: 1. resolving the server name to an IP address (or addresses!), and 2. actually opening a connection (which involves a handshake). When there are multiple addresses (e.g., IPv4 and IPv6) then Tcl tries them until it manages to get connected. (If you were using TLS/HTTPS, there would be even more going on behind the scenes.) _Name resolution is synchronous_ for a whole bunch of ugly reasons; I hate that.

Comment: To do a timeout, you do an asynchronous connect (option to `socket`) and use `after` to schedule a callback to stop the connect (by closing the socket) if it takes too long. This doesn't really help if name resolution is the problem, but works fine if it is the other server that simply isn't responding.

Comment: I read Donal Fellows comment and for now, I just added -async to socket with no after, and then tested. The socket does connect and passes the error but again, there is a long timout and the code simply crashs giving error flushing socket socketxxxxx socket not connected.